# Proper wiring for a HiLetgo DAC to Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, analog, dac

I have been having trouble finding any recourses for a DAC chip that I bought. It is the HiLetgo PCM5102 DCA.

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07Q9K5MT8/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Q9K5MT8)

There are 6 ports to be routed. VIN, GND (I know these) LCK, DIN, BCK, SCK, but the rest are a mystery to me. The Adafruit version has tutorials online but I got this one because of the built in 3.5mm jack is what I really needed. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if I need to post any other resources.

I am trying to read the audio data coming in from songs through the 3.5mm jack.

Here is the data sheet for the Adafruit version of the DCA with a 3.5mm audio jack

I am asking for help in reading audio data from the input jack.

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-i2s-stereo-decoder-uda1334a.pdf

Comment: @jsotola Hi, I actually am having trouble finding a data sheet online. I purchased this on amazon, but the product does not appear on the official HiLetgo website. As for a question I am asking what pins the LCK, BCK, DIN, and SCK slots are to be routed to

Comment: if you cannot find a datasheet for the module, then look for a datasheet for the main IC that is used in the module

Comment: `reading audio data from the input jack` ... the pictures at amazon are quite clear ... the jack is not an input

Comment: A DAC (Digital to Analog Converter) is an output device. You cannot read a signal with it. So the 3.5mm jack is an output (for example for headphones). For reading you need an ADC (Analog to Digital Converter). Also you would need to bias the voltage. Normal audio voltages on such jacks will vary around 0V, also going negative, which an ADC will not simply read (unless it does the biasing internally).

Comment: You have tagged this question as 'arduino-uno'.  The board you are asking about uses an I2S interface, which AFAIK is not available on the Uno.